# I am getting an error while trying to use SVM for classification a a dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

This is the code I used

```
svmclassifier = SVC(kernel = "rbf",random_state=0)
svmclassifier.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

And this is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QonD.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).

Answer (score 0):

this issue is always related to what is the type of your target `y_train`. It should always be in integer or you can encode the target using `LabelEncoder()`

Comment: How do I implement the LabelEncoder()

Comment: `from sklearn import preprocessing`
`enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()`
`y_target = enc.fit_transform(y_target)`

Comment: where y_target represents ??

Comment: Sorry, in your case it will be the y_train